# How to get Specific Image from Document And Media Folder in jsp

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have Successfully created folder and uploaded file in Document and Media Library.

I am storing File Name in DB and based on that file name I want to fetch that specific file from Document Library. I am new to Liferay.

I am fetching all Files saved in Document & Media Library using this Code Snippet. But is there any way to directly fetch File using File Name.

Here is my Code Snippet

```
public void getAllDLFileLink(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay,String folderName){      
         try {
             Folder folder =DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID, folderName);
             List<DLFileEntry> dlFileEntries = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), folder.getFolderId());
             for (DLFileEntry file : dlFileEntries) {
                    String url = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/" + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() + "/" + 
                                  file.getFolderId() +  "/" +file.getTitle() ;
                    System.out.println("DL Link=>"+url);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There are enough tutorials out there to help you out. We are not going to supply entire solutions for this.

Comment: You'll need more than the file name: The site (or technically groupId) and the folder (or full path) where you put it as well. Or just the documentId. Which one do you have? The Document Librarie's API starts with DL at http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/

Comment: @OlafKock : I have edited the Code Snippet. Pease help me.

Answer (score 0):

As your code snippet already finds the URL for a `DLFileEntry`, I'm assuming that you want to get hold of the binary content. Check [DLFileEntry.getContentStream()](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/DLFileEntry.html#getContentStream()).

If this assumption is wrong and you want to embed the image in the HTML output of your portlet, use the URL within an `<img src="URL-HERE"/>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(long groupId, long folderId, java.lang.String title)` to get file using file name / title, as following:

```
String fileName = "abc.jpg";
Folder folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),
    DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID, folderName);
DLFileEntry dlFileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(
    themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), folder.getFolderId(), fileName);
```

However, title is stored with extension, therefore, you will require to pass complete name of image / file.